# Error restarting: The zone '.../zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. '(resource type:compute)'

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a v100 instance, and I have not been able to restart it for the last 24 hours. This has never happened for this instance the last several months. Is this a GCP platform problem?

> (gcloud.compute.instances.start) The zone 'projects/XXX/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  '(resource type:compute)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's not an issue*, events like this happens from time to time. Let me explain:

1. When you [stop an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance) it releases some resources like vCPU and memory.
2. When you [start an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#starting_a_stopped_instance) (or change it) it requests resources like vCPU and memory back and if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get an error message:

   ```
   The zone 'projects/XXXX/zones/ZONE' does not have enough resources 
   available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again 
   later.
   ```

   more information available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

   > If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
   > or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
   > resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
   > request. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
   > and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.
3. Resource availability are depending from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

**There are a few ways to solve your issue**:

1. Move your instance to [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) by following [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).
2. Wait for a while and try to start your VM instance again.
3. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future (*extra payment required*):

> Create reservations for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific
> zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without
> additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for
> your workloads when you need them. After you create a reservation, you
> begin paying for the reserved resources immediately, and they remain
> available for your project to use indefinitely, until the reservation
> is deleted.

Comment: Thanks. The VM finally booted up after 48 hours of startup attempts.